# VB: How to loop through labels and change their text?

Tags: vb.net

I have 80 labels on my form, all named "lbl" and a number from 1 to 80 after that. I want to loop through them and set their Text property in a consecutive pattern e.g. 1, 2, 3 ... 80.

```
 Dim nr As Integer
    For nr = 1 To 80
        lbl(nr).Text = nr
    Next nr
```

I have this right now, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know of similar code that will do what I need?

Comment: There's no need to declare that `nr` variable outside the loop if you're only using it inside the loop. You can delete that first line altogether and the loop will still work. You can declare the loop counter with the `For` statement itself.

Comment: Also, while you don't have to do so, it is convention to use `i` for a `For` loop counter unless you have some specific reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```vb
lbl(nr).Text = nr
```

to this:

```vb
Controls("lbl" & nr).Text = nr
```

This assumes that the `Labels` are directly on the form. If they are on a `Panel` or some other container, use it's `Controls` collection instead of that of the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
'in WPF
      Dim i As Integer = 1
            For Each c In Me.gridMain.Children
                If c.GetType() Is GetType(Label) AndAlso c.Name Like "lbl*" Then
                    Dim _label As Label = c
                    _label.Content = "label" & i
                    i += 1
                End If
            Next

'in Winform
      Dim i As Integer = 1
            For Each c In Me.Controls
                If c.GetType() Is GetType(Label) AndAlso c.Name Like "lbl*" Then
                    Dim _label As Label = c
                    _label.Text = "label" & i
                    i += 1
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: Given that the OP said they have a form and are trying to set a `Text` property, I'm not sure that something in WPF is relevant. The OP should have specified WinForms but I think it can be safely inferred.

Comment: Hi, WPF or winform is the same, i edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

It would keep things tidy to put the code to do that in its own method. Then, you might have more than one container (such as Panels) that you want to set the text of the labels in, so you could pass that container as a parameter to the method.

As you want to use the number from the name of the label after some prefix, you can check for that prefix and then set the name to everything after the prefix, like this:

```
Sub SetLabelsText(container As Control)
    Const prefix = "lbl"

    For Each ctrl In container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        If ctrl.Name.StartsWith(prefix) Then
            ctrl.Text = ctrl.Name.Substring(prefix.Length)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Then if the container was named "Panel1" you would use

```
SetLabelsText(Panel1)
```

or if the labels were directly on the form and not in a container on the form:

```
SetLabelsText(Me)
```

With a method like that, you could also pass the prefix as a parameter to make it more versatile:

```
Sub SetLabelsText(container As Control, prefix As String)
    For Each ctrl In container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        If ctrl.Name.StartsWith(prefix) Then
            ctrl.Text = ctrl.Name.Substring(prefix.Length)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

and call it like

```
SetLabelsText(Me, "lbl")
```

---

However, if the labels are laid out in some pattern that you could create with a for loop or two, it could be somewhat easier to create them programatically and set the text at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have controls numbered from 1-80 and you want to access them in a loop.

You will need to actually put them in an array before you can run your loop. This will require finding all your textboxes on the form if you have any nested controls.

I wrote up a little test app and here's what I came up with:

First, a list to hold all the textboxes we want to process, and a sub to fill it.

```
    Public numberTextBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)

    ' A function that finds all the desired textboxes and saves them
    Public Sub InitializeTextBoxes()
        Dim controls = GetAllTextBoxes(Me)

        For Each formTextBox As TextBox In controls
            Dim textBoxName As String = formTextBox.Name

            If textBoxName.StartsWith("TextBox") Then
                Dim textBoxNumber As Integer

                ' verify that this has a number after the TextBox part
                If Integer.TryParse(textBoxName.Substring(7), textBoxNumber) Then
                    numberTextBoxes.Add(formTextBox)
                End If

            End If
        Next formTextBox
    End Sub
```

`GetAllTextBoxes(Me)` is a function that returns all the TextBoxes contained on a control. If you just look through all the controls on the Form without looking through the child controls, you will miss nested items.

I'll fill that in below.

Next, a function to get the number off the end of the names, and a function to actually change the textboxes:

```
    ' extracts the number from the end of a textbox's string
    Public Function GetTbNum(textBoxName As String) As Integer
        If (textBoxName.Length > 2) Then
            GetTbNum = CInt(textBoxName.Substring("TextBox".Length))
        End If
    End Function

    ' a function to change the names on the textboxes
    Public Sub FillTextBoxes()
        ' Note that Arrays and Lists are usually 0-based
        For i = 0 To numberTextBoxes.Count - 1
            Dim tb As TextBox = numberTextBoxes(i)

            ' if you want to set the text to the number at the end of the name
            numberTextBoxes(i).Text = GetTbNum(numberTextBoxes(i).Name)
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Finally, the function to return all the textboxes on a form as a list. If you know your Form only is ever going to contain the textboxes on the very top level, you could just loop through `MyForm.Controls` and find those textboxes, but this will work on any way you have your form laid out.

```
    Function GetAllTextBoxes(control As Control, Optional textBoxList As List(Of TextBox) = Nothing) As List(Of TextBox)
        If textBoxList Is Nothing Then
            textBoxList = New List(Of TextBox)

            GetAllTextBoxes(control, textBoxList)
            GetAllTextBoxes = textBoxList
        Else
            If (TypeOf control Is TextBox) Then
                textBoxList.Add(control)
            End If

            For Each item In control.Controls
                GetAllTextBoxes(item, textBoxList)
            Next item
        End If
    End Function
```

Now, in the Form's intitializer, you can call the functions:

```
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        InitializeTextBoxes()
        FillTextBoxes()
    End Sub
```

There's lots of things that could be done differently here but hopefully that's a decent start on what you would need to do something like this.

Of course you could add a variable for the name of the textboxes you wanted to look at, or change how you set the text; also, you could sort the list if you end up getting your controls out-of-order, etc.